# Extract substring from variable in Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

Edited:
I wrote this playbook but it does not show the extracted variable:

```
---
- hosts: fppc
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: xyz  
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: N1
    ios_command:
       commands:
         - sh run | i bann          
    register: sr

  - debug: msg="{{ sr.stdout}}"

  - set_fact: 
      rid: "{{ sr.stdout | regex_search('.*ID: (..)')  }}"

  - debug: msg="{{ rid }}"
```

Execution:

```
ansible@Ansible:~$ ansible-playbook pb1.yml

PLAY [fppc] *************************************************************************

TASK [N1] ***************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.250.161]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.250.161] => {
    "msg": [
        "banner login ^CID: A4"
    ]
}

TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.250.161]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ sr.stdout | regex_search('.*ID: (..)')  }}): expected string or buffer"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/ansible/pb1.retry

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
192.168.250.161            : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   

ansible@Ansible:~$
```

Comment: Try printing 'rid' first - Ansible complains that 'rid' does not have a property called 'output'. It is possible that you have a json string, rather than a datastructure?

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution:

```
---
- hosts: fppc
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: xyz
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: N1
    ios_command:
       commands:
         - sh run         
    register: sr

  - set_fact:
      temp: "{{ sr.stdout_lines | join }}"

  - set_fact:
      rid: "{{  temp | regex_replace('.*ID: (..).*', '\\1')  }}"

  - debug: msg="{{ rid }}"
```

Execution:

```
ansible@Ansible:~$ ansible-playbook pb1.yml

PLAY [fppc] ********************************************************************

TASK [N1] **********************************************************************
ok: [192.168.250.161]

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [192.168.250.161]

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [192.168.250.161]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.250.161] => {
    "msg": "A4"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.250.161            : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution, more logical:

```
---
- hosts: fppc
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: xyz
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: N1
    ios_command:
       commands:
         - sh run         
    register: sr

  - set_fact: 
      rid: "{{ sr.stdout | regex_search('(?<=ID:)\\s+\\S+', multiline=True) | trim }}"

  - debug: msg="{{ rid }}"
```

Execution:

```
ansible@Ansible:~$ ansible-playbook pb1.yml

PLAY [fppc] ********************************************************************

TASK [N1] **********************************************************************
ok: [192.168.250.161]

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [192.168.250.161]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.250.161] => {
    "msg": "A4"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.250.161            : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```